# SP07 Designer - Reset to the default list EditFrom.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, aspx, edit-form, newform

I want to reset **EditForm.aspx** and **NewForm.aspx** to default for the list, because confused.

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

List -> List Settings -> there is some Info Path forms server settings link that leads to the page where you can remove customization.

Changing default Edit/New pages will not help - you need to modify pages for default content type of this list if you want to go this route.

You can also able to do this in SharePoint without needing SP Designer.

1. Navigate to the list in SharePoint.
2. On the List ribbon bar, click List Settings.
3. Under General Settings, click Form Settings link (bottom of first column).
4. Select the Use the default SharePoint Form option.

You can also opt to delete the custom form by checking Delete the InfoPath Form from the server.

The ans is collecting from this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167513/how-to-reset-sharepoint-2010-list-forms-from-infopath-to-the-default-forms).

Comment: I dont find this path..